# Decorator for getting current user NestJs + MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, nestjs

I'm using NestJs + MongoDb
This custom decorator doesn't give me current user. I get the first user from my database.
I've checked this from different users and I always get the same answer.

Decorator:

```
export const CurrentUser = createParamDecorator((data, req): UserModel => {
  const request = req.switchToHttp().getRequest();
  return request.user
});
```

Controller

```
    @UseGuards(AuthGuard('jwt'))
    @UsePipes(new ValidationPipe())
    @HttpCode(200)
    @Patch(':friendId')
    @Auth() 
    async toggleFriend(
        @CurrentUser() user: UserModel,
    ) {
        console.log('CurrentUser', user)
    }
```

Comment: How do you populate `req.user`?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: You have to populate the `user` property of the `request` somehow. If you use passport, or `@nestjs/passport`, then the returned value of the `validate` method is usually how this is set

Comment: Can you write how the code should look like, please?

Comment: Which part? I'm trying to get a better idea of _how_ your code works

Comment: How to populate the user of the request

Comment: I figured you already had it populated as you were already trying to retrieve it. It's not like your server is just gonna know that random HTTP request from some IP is related to some user

Comment: You have an `AuthGuard('jwt'` being used, so probably the return of your `JwtStrategy#validate` is what is becoming `req.user` because that's how passport works

Answer (score 2):

Study below section, from it you will be able to understand how information is added to the authorization token and then further extraction of this information.
https://docs.nestjs.com/security/authentication#jwt-functionality